# Panel-collapse começar fechado

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Estou com o seguinte código: https://jsfiddle.net/05913dg4/1/

Eu preciso fazer com que esse `collapse`, comece fechado. Ou seja, quando abrir a página ele começar fechado, e só depois de clicar ele abrir....

Comment: Conforme o teu exemplo, deixa posto a classe `panel-collapsed` junto com a sua classe `panel-body` que em tese ele tem que abrir fechado

Comment: Como? Poderia editar o js fiddle e postar?

Comment: na verdade, a resposta do @Paulo esta correta, poderia postar o js fiddle com os seus botões?

Comment: Eu ja postei e atualizei o código. Verifique no js fiddle. Eu estou usando o bootstrap e o fontawesome. Talvez o jsfiddle não esteja lendo.

Comment: Encontrei [esse fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wc4xt/1052/) no Google, tem o que você precisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só configurar o HTML como se ele estivesse "*colapsado*", ou seja.

- No *heading* você vai adicionar a classe `panel-collapsed`;
- Coloque o icone correspondente ao estado *colapsed*, `fa-angle-down` eu imagino;
- Adicione a propriedade `display: none;` a classe `.panel-body`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.panel-heading', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
 if(!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
  $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
  $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');
        
  $this.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-angle-up').addClass('fa fa-angle-down');
 } else {
  $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
  $this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');
        
  $this.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-angle-down').addClass('fa fa-angle-up');
 }
});
```

```css
.panel-heading {
    background-color: #6f5499;
}

.panel-body {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 25px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    
    <div class="panel-heading panel-collapsed">
       <h3 class="panel-title" style="padding: 15px;"><center> COMO CHEGAR?</center></h3>
       <span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0;">
        <p>content virá aqui....</p>                 
                                         
    </div>
    
</div>
```

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8127zhq/1/)

Comment: Show! O meu único problema é que estou usando isso para carregar um maps do google. Ai quando clico pra abrir, o maps vem tudo bugado. Provavelmente é algo relacionado ao carregamento dele por parte do DOM.

Answer (score 1):

É só acrecentar `display: none;` ao CSS:

```
.panel-body {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 25px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Paulo, se eu fizer desta forma os meus ícones não funcionam. Eu preciso que o up e o down acompanhe as minhas ações pelo js. Ao abrir e visualizar, o icone esta para cima da seta, ao clicar ele abre o panel e o icone fica para cima, e assim por diante.